# Where should I write my javascript code for querying couchDB

Tags: javascript, html

I have to upload this code to the fouton interface. How can I query without uploading the file or without using cURL?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Tiny CouchApp</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Tiny CouchApp</h1>
      <ul id="databases"></ul>
   </body>
   <script src="/_utils/script/jquery.js"></script>   <script
      src="/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js"></script>   <script>
      $.couch.allDbs({
        success : function(dbs) {
          dbs.forEach(function(db) {
            $("#databases").append('<li><a href="/_utils/database.html?'+db+'">'+db+'</a></li>');
          });
        }
      });   
   </script> 
</html>
```